# How to play video after div display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

- i have one div inside div a video.
- default div is display hide
- when show div display auto-play video (jquery)
- all thing do with jquery/javascript
- i have no code for this

i am trying to play video after display div. i have one Launch Invitation page with timer when timer finished then video will be play automatically.

[Like this i have page](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_countdown)

Comment: If you post the code you allready have it's more likely that someone can hep you.

Comment: sorry but i have no code. i have only example like this---https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_countdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way of doing it, is to trigger a call when their is a changes on css style.

So it will be as:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutationRecord) {
        alert('play Video!');
    });    
});

var target = document.getElementById('d1');
observer.observe(target, { attributes : true, attributeFilter : ['style'] });

$('#d1').css('display', 'block');
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hs7ed3qb/1/

good luck :)